# Подскажите, в чем ошибка

Tags: php, html, файлы

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка. Файл не создает почему-то... Вот код:

```
$file = "php/test_db.phpdb";
$f = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($f, '$data[] = array("nickname" => "ADMIN", "name" => "Aleksandrs", "surname" => "Kornijenko", "group" => "mlm", "type" => "admin");'.PHP_EOL) or die('l');
fwrite($f, '$data[] = array("nickname" => "ADMIN", "name" => "Aleksandrs", "surname" => "Kornijenko", "group" => "mlm", "type" => "admin");'.PHP_EOL);
fclose($f);
```

С правами все в порядке.

`$file = "php/test_db.php";` не работает!

Убрал `fwrite()`, не работает!

`fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file, 'w');` не работает!

Comment: $file = "php/test_db.php"; ?  как вариант

Comment: А почему вы уверены про права. Уберите fwrite. Файл должен создаться

Comment: Эмм.. Путь то относительный, быть может файл создаётся не в том месте, где Вы его ищете? Попробуйте fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file, 'w');

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "php/test_db.php";
//запишет: путь/до/root_папки/сайта/php/test_db.php

$file = __DIR__ . "php/test_db.php";
//запишет: путь/до/папки_с_файлом_исполняющим_скрипт/php/test_db.php
```

Comment: или использовать константу `__DIR__`

Comment: @Jean-Claude да, можно, если точно известно что новый файл создаётся в той же папке, где лежит файл который запускает скрипт. Спасибо, дополню ответ.

Comment: слеш пропустил `__DIR__ . "/php/test_db.php"`